# How are Vulcans that don't strive for logic treated?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, society

While in history, there were a number of Vulcans who rejected logic, and fought wars with the majority that did ([one of which](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_of_Awakening) resulted in the Romulan Star Empire), what happens to modern-day Vulcans (TOS-era and later) that reject logic and refuse to follow and idealize it? Humans seem to have a vast spectrum of philosophies, but I can't recall ever seeing any illogical vulcans, at least any that don't actively strive to be as logical as possible.

There are probably at least a few vulcans that don't follow the cultural norm, as with nearly every other main Trek species (Klingons, Humans)

If the majority of Vulcans are so logical, how are those that aren't treated by the rest of Vulcan society?

Comment: [Sybok](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Sybok)

Comment: Not following logic actually makes Vulcans ill. If they persistently refuse to embrace logic (or find an alternative to logic, like Sybok) then the implication is that they simply go insane or die

Comment: Not canon- http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Followers_of_T'Vet

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We have cases of this in Enterprise. the [V'Tosh Ka'Tur](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/V%27tosh_ka%27tur) "Vulcans without Logic" are a group that *Enterprise* (NX-01) encounters.

This group while not abandoning logic, instead open up to emotions, and make decisions that take into account both logical, and emotional considerations. They were scoffed at by mainstream Vulcans and by T'Pol, the resident Vulcan currently on board the *Enterprise* (NX-01), but the Vulcans themselves did not overtly persecute, nor harass these Vulcans.

Comment: Accepting this answer because I think it will be of the most use to people finding this question through Google (though the answer below is very helpful as well; if you're reading this, look at that too!)

Answer (score 21):

The only arguably "illogical Vulcans" we see TOS or later are few and far between.

- [Sybok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sybok) lived apart from Vulcan society. Some apocrypha indicates that he was banished. Other sources, Gene Roddenberry included, indicate that Star Trek V is itself apocryphal.
- [Valeris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Valeris), for her acts which Spock considered illogical, was arguably mind-raped on the bridge of The Enterprise, then presumably imprisoned by Starfleet and/or The Federation. Her standing in Vulcan society is unknown, but Spock doesn't appear to have suffered any significant social consequences for *his* actions in her regard.
- [Sarek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarek), as he succumbed to [Bendii Syndrome](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bendii_Syndrome), was surreptitiously bolstered by his aides, then isolated. Vulcan society apparently was fine with this.
- [T'Paal](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T'Paal_%28isolationist%29) presumably went directly to jail, did not collect 200 quatloos. She lived apart from Vulcan society, and its long term response to her is unknown.
- [Chu'lak](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chu'lak) was illogical as a result of a mental illness. His fate is not revealed, but treatment seems likely.
- [Tuvok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tuvok), on rejecting logic as an adolescent, was sent away for <strike>brainwashing</strike> study with a Vulcan Master to get him back on track.

Comment: An interesting note. The word "apocryphal" actually literally just means "unknown author."  However, it is almost always used to mean "false" or "urban legend". It's a bit like: the word "decimate" literally means "to kill one-tenth of the group" (note the "deci-"), but it is almost always used to mean "annihilated".

Answer (score 3):

Politank-Z already mentioned Sybok, who is a prime example of a Vulcan rejecting logic.

Another example is brought to us in the episode "Fusion" (S1E17 of ST: Enterprise). Here, Archer and T'Pol encounter a ship of V'Tosh Ka'Tur who are outcasts from Vulcan society.

And since we're listing logic-compromising afflictions, let's not forget Pon-Farr.